# How to calculate the distance between 2 or more points? C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have four citys : A, B,C and D. The distances ar AB - 5 miles BC - 4 miles - CD - 5 miles - AD - 3 miles. I want to calculete this rote: A-D-B-C. How can i do that?

Comment: Sounds more like a trigonometry question than a programming one

Comment: This question was answered 2,500 years ago.  Google "Pythagoras".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know the distances, don't you? In any case, you can use the [distance formula.](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm) Just plug the points' x and y coordinates into it.